# Retrieve Braintree Customer ID

Tags: braintree

How do I retrieve the customer id from my sale result with braintree.  I am able to get the transaction id but I do not understand the results fully.  Thanks

```
$result = $gateway->transaction()->sale($sale);

if ($result->success){

    $btree_cust_id = $result->transaction->customer->id;

    $btree_transacton_id = $result->transaction->id;

    echo "Braintree Customer ID : ".$btree_cust_id." Transaction ID: ".$btree_transacton_id; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

According to the [Braintree developer docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/), a [Transaction result object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/result-objects/) has a [`customerDetails`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/#customer_details) attribute which itself has an [`id`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/#customer_details.id) attribute.

As such, you can retrieve the customer id with `$result->transaction->customerDetails->id`.

Comment: Thanks Shea, I understand it now.  Thanks

Comment: When using the sandbox, it seems like the customerDerails are not defined